# New custom class file not appearing

Tags: ios, xcode5

I am trying to create an app on Xcode5, nothing major it's my first one.

I'm having trouble getting a new file to appear in the custom class called "game" (files that will be created will be game.h and game.m)

I create a new file after right clicking on the project name on the top left corner, clicking new file then "objective-c class", I rename it to "game" hit create and it's done, they both appear straight away under the project name, I then drag them down to the other files to keep everything tidy.

I then highlight the second view screen or game screen, click the third icon at the top right corner go to the custom class drop down options to change the second view to "game" but it's not there???

I've deleted and retried this too many times to mention, and need it to change from "view controller" to "game" ...

Am I missing something somewhere?

Comment: In the subclass field did you make sure it said UIViewController? When you try to set the class of your game view in IB what does it say initially? It is good practice to append ViewController to subclasses of `UIViewController`, for instance` GameViewController`.

Comment: If my answer is exactly what you are looking for, please upvote and mark as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're creating a `UIViewController` subclass, it should have the suffix `ViewController`, but this shouldn't effect the problem you're having.

Sometimes it is necessary to SAVE the newly created file before it will auto-complete in the custom class field for storyboards and xibs.  With that said though, just because it doesn't auto-complete doesn't mean it won't work right.  You can still type the name of the class in (assuming you type it correctly) and it will work as expected.

If you still have doubts, go to the newly created file, CMD+S to save, now go back to the UI file and everything should work fine.

Also, make sure you've got the write UI object selected.  The placeholder text in the custom class box should match whatever the class you subclassed is.

Answer (score 0):

`click the third icon at the top right corner`  = He is talking about The **Identity Inspector** for XCode Project.

For your information, when you just created a new subclass with **.H** and **.M**, you will have to wait some time (1-5 minutes) for XCode to index those files before they appear inside The **Identity Inspector**.

If you do not want to wait, after you created the new subclass, close the entire XCode project by clicking on the **Red X button** on the **top left corner** and then reopen the project. The Xcode will index those files when you launch the project.